What magic items can a druid in animal form still access?
What items might still be usable? If a player takes a magic ring from a larger  or smaller monster and he can use it, why can't the panther he turns into? command word items, sized items armor and weapons, don't think so. Magical clothes, amulets, bracers, gloves, what would still work and what melds into the new form?
I've done a lot of research, and I would love any RAW information you have on this.

There are effectively two considerations in this question:

what types of magic items can animals generally use?
how does the druid’s wild shape affect that?

Animal Magic Items
The first and most obvious limitation is that most animals do not have hands, or any reasonable replacement. That prevents the use of most weapons, tools, and shields—magic or otherwise.
As for worn magic items, the core rules don’t really cover how those work for non-humanoid characters; the list of magic item slots is described for “A humanoid-shaped body.” There are a few core rules for items for other creatures, such as barding for quadrupeds instead of humanoid armor, but for the most part, we need to turn to the Rules Compendium:

Most creatures have all the normal body slots available. Creatures never gain extra body slots for having extra body parts. For unusual cases, here are some guidelines.

(Rules Compendium pg. 83)
It then goes on to say that while magic armor, shields, and weapons will refit themselves to match a new wearer, this feature only works within the same size category (and, in the case of armors, general body plan). They won’t change size categories for you (unless you have something special granting that effect).
And then it goes on to remove item slots from fingerless (no rings), armless (no arms, hands, or rings), headless (no face, head, or throat), and legless (no feet) creatures. Creatures with no clear shape at all—like oozes—don’t get any item slots at all. But for the most part, as long as you’ve got a head, at least one forelimb and at least one hindlimb (or more than two hindlimbs), you can use all of the usual magic item slots.
For most animals, therefore, you have all of the magic item slots, but cannot use magic items that must be held or manipulated in your hands.
Workarounds
You can continue to use things that require hands if your wild shape form still has them—which usually means apes, at least until you start dealing in elementals.
A weapon with the mouthpick special property from Lords of Madness can be used by any creature that has a bite attack (which they lose while using the mouthpick weapon). This is basically great grey wolf Sif from Dark Souls, which is pretty cool. Somewhat pricey though.
Or just use the animal’s natural weapons, and focus more on worn magic items. An amulet of mighty fists is overpriced, but if you have enough natural attacks (3+), it becomes competitive. The necklace of natural attacks from Savage Species is generally better, though.
As for worn items, most animals don’t have any issue there. The only major category of animals that’s in trouble are the snakes. The only real solution there—at least under Rules Compendium rules—is to make your arms-, hands-, ring-, and feet-slot items in other slots, which (at least per the usual guidelines) costs 50% extra, which is very expensive. You could try asking your DM to use the Savage Species rules, though, which allow different body plans to use items in weird ways, and might allow some variant version of those slots even for snakes. (The other option is to just suggest to your DM that this guideline is a rather poor idea—which it is—and that this markup isn’t actually appropriate—which it isn’t.)
Wild Shape Issues
The basic impediment is this:

Any gear worn or carried by the druid melds into the new form and becomes nonfunctional.

Thus, normally, none of your gear is accessible when you use wild shape. If the item has been melded into your body, absolutely no one—including you—can get at it until your wild shape ends.
Workarounds
There are a couple of ways around this: the most obvious is, simply don’t have the item when you use wild shape. If you drop something or give it to an ally or whatever, it won’t meld into you when you use wild shape, and then you can pick it up or your ally can give it back to you, and you can put it back on.
This procedure is cumbersome and potentially risky. Wild shape does last for hours on end, so it can be done, but it makes leaving and returning to wild shape very annoying—you’ll have a strong incentive to avoid doing that and just staying in the one form for as long as you can. That can be problematic since you can’t talk in wild shape.
A wilding clasp from Magic Item Compendium solves this problem: by attaching this item to any of your worn magic items, you prevent that item from melding into your body, and it instead reshapes to fit your new form (“as long as the item could reasonably be
worn by the new form,” which means it probably doesn’t help snakes unless you’re using a fairly-generous interpretation of the Savage Species rules). But it also adds 4,000 gp to the cost of every magic item you’re wearing (and want to keep), which gets pricey. Still cheaper than the 50% markup on unusual-slot items.

@justhalf That they’re for the 5th edition of D&D and this question and answer are all about the “v.3.5 revised edition” from 2004, which didn’t have them.

Ah, I missed the tag. Thanks!

Animals appear to be able to wear most magic items.
By default, your equipment disappears when you wild shape:

Any gear worn or carried by the druid melds into the new form and becomes nonfunctional.

If you can avoid that drawback (e.g. by removing the items before entering wild shape, or by some feat, prestige class ability, or a benevolent DM), the Dungeon Master's Guide only mentions the item slots for a humanoid body. However, animals wearing magic items is supported in various sourcebooks and magazine articles.
According to Tome and Blood p.18-19, "Familiars and Magic Items", animals can wear most magic items:

What magic items can familiars use? Since most fit users of any size, the simple answer is quite a few. ...
Page 176 of the Dungeon Master's Guide sets out where a humanoid creature can wear various types of items. Familiars have equivalent locations. For example, a quadruped uses its back feet for items worn on the feet and its front feet for those worn on the hands. for avians, treat the feet and legs as hands and arms and the wings as legs and feet. ...
Your DM may decide that some items don't fit your familiar's body type ... In most cases, even if your familiar ecan't use a given item, it's possible to make (or to have made) a usable equivalent.

Animals can't use an item if they lack the physical ability. A snake can't wear boots because it has no feet or equivalent, can't use a sword or shield because it lacks arms to wield it with, and can't use command word activated items since it can't speak. Other than this, there's a broad acceptance of animals wearing both standard items on equivalent body slots, and specialized equivalents adapted to their body type.
A similar sentiment is expressed in the Dragon Magazine #308 article "Heavy Gear: Dragon Magic Items and Equipment". It specifies that a dragon can wear one headband, hat, helmet, crown, diadem, or skullcap; a pair of goggles or lenses; a cloak, cape, or mantle; an amulet, brooch, medallion, necklace, or periapt; a robe; a vest, vestment or shirt; a pair of bracers or bracelets; a pair of gloves or gauntlets; two rings; a belt; and a pair of boots. These are often made specially to fit a dragon. They can also drink potions, wear armor if proficient, and even wield a specially made tail blade. However, it cannot wield normal weapons or shields.
Draconomicon p.24 repeats the rules in this magazine article, with minor changes, notably slightly expanding the definition of which items they can use - "any" magic item, rather than merely "many":

Because magic items that must be worn will fit users of any size, a dragon can use any magic item a humanoid character can.

Masters of the Wild suggests that an animal can only wear one collar, saddle, or bridle at a time, which indicates that those items take the necklace slot. That sourcebook also introduces the Opposable weapon enhancement, which allows any creature with a limb to wield a weapon even if they lack opposable thumbs; the Wild armor enhancement, which allows the wearer to retain the effect of the armor in wild shape; and the wilding clasp, a small gold chain which can be attached to any item to allow it to retain its use in wild shape.
Savage Species p.23 further asserts that an animal can even wear an item in a non-traditional manner:

While it is possible for such creatures to wear and use some magic items (a wolf could wear a magic ring in its ear, for instance), they cannot use many weapons and tools common to adventurers. DMs may soon tire of asking, "How are you holding that?"

Savage Species also suggests that creatures are still limited to the human number of magic item slots, as there's a feat called Extra Item Space which allows, say, a two-headed creature to benefit from two magic helmets. This limitation may be relevant to the druid if they assume, say, the form of a large insect and attempt to wear multiple pairs of boots.
Dragon Magazine #338 p.91, "Animal Magic", mentions animals wearing magic armor and collars, the latter taking the amulet slot. Dragon #313, "Eye Wares", describes that beholders can wear a ring on their eye stalks (though like humanoids they may benefit form no more than two rings at a time), or hold a staff or wand in their mouth or by telekinesis, or wear specially made armor.
The general tendency I see is that you don't need a humanoid body to use magic items. As long as you have an equivalent body part, the item will adjust to fit your body size and shape.

Tome and Blood is kind of an awkward source to cite for this, being 3.0e. Savage Species is somewhat awkward, too, since it’s one of the “3.25e” books. Rules Compendium has a similar statement, with more detail, that’s solidly and clearly for 3.5e. It does contradict Savage Species some, though.

Detailed rules for dragons & magic items are also on page 24 of the Draconomicon.

@Peregrin Interestingly, Draconomicon p.24 is nearly identical to the description in the Dragon #308 article. The latter was published only five months earlier (June 2003 vs November 2003), and oddly is uncredited in the book, even though it credits other Dragon articles.
